# proportion comparison across two populations - one non normal distributed

Tags: p-value, z-score

I'm new to this website, so, please apologize if this question have already been posted and replied. I checked around and it looks like it haven't. In case I'm wrong, please redirect me to the right page.

I'm working with protein sequences. I have a sample that I want to compare with a reference. The purpose is to understand if under some conditions there is an higher expression of some amino acids. The two distributions I'm comparing are composed of the residue name (e.g. P or A) and a percentage (e.g. 8.6 or 7.3) coming from their frequency of appearance in the specimen and in the reference. I also have the number of samples composing the two populations.

Said that, I calculated z-distributions on top of which I calculated p-values. But I have many concerns (consider I'm not a statistician), as follows:
1) do the two distributions have to be normal (to be compared by z-distribution)? Reference it's normally distributed (checked with jarque.bera.test and ad.test from R), the one from my specimen it's not
2) if the answer to 1 is "yes", do you have any idea (I guess and I hope so!) on how to compare those two distributions? Kolmogorov-Smirnov shouldn't be ok, since it's conceived for continuous distributions. Am I wrong?

Please also consider that the two populations are of 131 and 554,241 entries. As far as I know tests like the t test perform better with small specimen.

Many thanks for considering my questions,
Best wishes, 
Luca